# Create Purchase Order screen disappearing values

Tags: acumatica

As per title. Some values will disappear or blank out when selecting the row. How do I stop the values from disappearing ?

[image]

TIA

Comment: I think this screen uses a view delegate, are these fields added and set in the view delegate? I assume these are non standard fields and you have modified the screen to include them? can you include the graph code you have for adding the fields currently?

Comment: Its not customised if that's what you mean.  But some fields are shown depending on modules enabled e.g. Manufacturing, Production Order, Service Order etc.

Comment: I see the same results in 23r1 sales demo. Since this is not a code issue I suggest reaching out on the Acumatica communities page and/or creating a case.